# Difference between Algorithm and Code

Tags: algorithms, terminology

A few days ago I had a conversation with a Civil Engineer with a background in Pascal and BASIC, and we talked about programming in Python. When I was talking, I used the term "code" to refer to a Python program, and he told me that he didn't know what "code" was, that the correct term was "algorithm", and that "code" was something else.

I really didn't know how to refute him because the way I see it is that a program can be an "algorithm". I used that term only when I was starting to program simple programs. The word I use most is "code", and on the internet, almost everyone else uses that term.

When does something go from being an algorithm to being code, if it can change. Maybe it can be both at the same time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77757/difference-between-a-pseudo-code-and-algorithm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between a pseudo code and algorithm?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77757/difference-between-a-pseudo-code-and-algorithm)

Comment: Note, when you say code, in context of programming, this can mean "source code" or "pseudo code" (as well as some other things which you probably did not have in mind). The distinction between "source code" and "algorithm" is much clearer than between "pseudo code" and "algorithm", so if you avoid to say just "code", that could help to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: In the context of Python I would think "code" refers to "source code", not pseudo code

Comment: @Todd: and in the context of algorithms I would think code refers more likely to pseudo code. That's exactly my point.

Comment: What is your definition of "code"? What is your definition of "algorithm"? What is your colleague's definition of "code"? What is your colleague's definition of algorithm? Have you verified your two definitions of "code" agree with each other? Have you verified that your two definitions of "algorithm" agree with each other?

Comment: @DocBrown Does it though? How would you refer to the actual code then? I mean, I don't recall ever seeing the bare word "code" used to implictly mean pseudocode, except perhaps in an unambiguous context, i.e. when referring to some pseudocode that was already presented, or perhaps when explicitly stating it's an approximation: _"the code might look something like this: <writes pseudocode>"_. Did you see it happen in a more ambiguous ways?

Comment: Please note that, as already mentioned, the term "code" may have a completely different meaning for a civil engineer: https://www.asce.org/codes-and-standards/codes-and-standards/

Comment: @JörgWMittag The truth is that we didn't get that far on the subject, we simply didn't go on because I got stuck, I've never been faced with such a question before. And as far as I can see, the answer is not so precise, there are many points of view, similar, but with interesting variations.

Comment: @Bob__ How interesting, so basically, when I decide to resume such a discussion with this person I would have to make it clear that our two branches (Civil and Computer Science) handle (perhaps) different concepts of the word _"code"_... And go from there with that clear.

Comment: "a Civil Engineer with a background in Pascal and BASIC, and we talked about programming in Python" - I think that's pretty clear, we have plenty of context and SO questions are about context. It's not talking about pseudo-code.

Comment: I guess he would understand the difference between a design or even a blueprint and a bridge. The algorithm is analagous to the design, your code to the bridge. Not a perfect analogy but it should lead him to a better understanding.

Comment: What is the difference between "abstract" and "concrete"?

Comment: @Jalkhov Easy, just use “source code” instead of “code” to disambiguate. That said, I don't think the conversation you had suffered from that confusion.

Comment: Code implements an algorithm.

Comment: Makes me think of Algol, the algorithm oriented language.  An Algol program is code, and it generally presents an algorithm.

Comment: @Jalkhov 'Code' in programming is short for 'source code'.  'Code' is potentially ambiguous but 'source code' is pretty specific to software.

Comment: "I really didn't know how to refute him"? Why do you wish to refute him? That would imply that you have a counter-argument which you clearly lack. Maybe seek to understand before attempting to refute. Code is used to achieve an algorithm. You should expand on how exactly you phrased your statement.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I said "refute" because I simply didn't know how to argue against it, because I knew it wasn't like he said, but I wasn't clear why.

Comment: I understand that. "Refute" implies an argumentative stance. You will find life gets easier once you start trying to understand instead of argue. Just because you listened to someone does not mean you agreed with them. Depending on how you actually phrased your "code" statement I could very well be inclined to agree with the other person; I don't know. Your question does not provide enough context.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus "I used the term 'code' to refer to a Python program, and he told me that he didn't know what 'code' was".  This doesn't give enough context, really?  I think the OP is likely not a native English speaker (but proficient in English).  I think instead of 'refute' the appropriate word is 'correct' or 'inform' but the  personal dynamic might not allow that.

Comment: @JimmyJames You are right, my native language is not English, and you are also right that the term refute was not correct, I think I would correct it to "respond/opinionate".

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In short, while there are differences in the specific meaning of the words, that civil engineer was being needlessly pedantic and balking at you not using his preferred word. There was no justifiable reason to disrupt the flow of conversation other than them wanting to be a clever know-it-all.

---

Arguing over the "algorithm" vs "code" moniker is like arguing whether what I'm sitting on right now is "furniture" or a "chair". These are not exact synonyms of one another and in some cases it can be one without being the other, but the specific designation really doesn't matter in scope of the current conversation.

An algorithm is [defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm):

> In mathematics and computer science, an algorithm is an effective method expressed as a finite list of well-defined instructions for calculating a function. Algorithms are used for calculation, data processing, and automated reasoning.

All code is essentially an algorithm. It's a sequence of well-defined instructions to get the computer to do the thing you want it to do.

**Can you have code that is not an algorithm?**

Pedants might argue that declarations (e.g. `public class Foo {}`) are not algorithms and only operations (e.g. `int c = b + a;` can be considered algorithms.

I don't quite agree, as the declarations are essential to the *well-defined* nature of the instructions (as they define the data used in the operations). In essence, if your language's native definition of `int` is acceptable, then my custom definition of `class Foo` is as well. I see no reason to distinguish between the two in this regard.

**Can you have an algorithm that is not code?**

Yes. Any set of calculation instructions is an algorithm. This could be a handwritten list of steps on how to e.g. calculate the length of the hypotenuse of a right triangle (i.e. Pythagoras' theorem):

> 1. Square the length of each leg.
> 2. Add them together.
> 3. Take the square root.

This is not code, but it is an algorithm.

The furthest stretch I could give in favor of that civil engineer's argument is that you could argue that a *compiled* application is still an algorithm but has ceased to be code. But I doubt you were specifically talking about a compiled file, given that Python is an interpreted language, at which point this argument doesn't even apply in the civil engineer's favor.

As an aside, while most definitions tend to restrict algorithms to the fields of mathematics and computer science, I personally see no reason why we couldn't consider e.g. a cooking recipe as an algorithm as well. It's still a sequence of well-defined instructions to achieve a specific predetermined outcome. But this is maybe a subjective argument and you might feel differently.

Comment: +1 the "furniture vs chair" illustration is perfect. I interpret algorithms to be conceptual, and code to be the manifestation of that concept in a particular programming language.

Comment: In talking about algorithms, recipes are often used as a practical example.  Many CS people are cooks, but not all cooks are CS people. :-)

Comment: I have to disagree a bit: algorithms are recipes, yes, but code is an implementation of the algorithm in a particular language.  Indeed, you could even have somewhat different implementations in the same language.

Comment: @jamesqf agreed. an "algorithm" is more of an equivalence class on programs, which are each expressed in code. For instance, the abstract notion of "quicksort" in an algorithm, and any implementation of it is code. And compiled bytecode is - well, it's in the name. You can talk about the algorithm implemented with a piece of code, but then you don't talk about the code itself.

Comment: "Can you have code that is not an algorithm?" -- apart from program code, 'code' also means things like _"a system of signals or symbols for communication"_, (encoding) e.g. the Morse code, or the [8b/10b code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8b/10b_encoding)

Comment: @jamesqf: What you say is correct to the letter, but somewhat irrelevant when considering normal speech. Point in place: is [this](https://media.newyorker.com/photos/5a82035156b75c08a3e5b5b4/16:9/w_1900,h_1068,c_limit/Cunningham-Obama-Kehinde-Wiley.jpg) Barack Obama or George W Bush? Did you say Obama? Well, it's not even _a painting of_ Obama, it's _a picture of a painting of_ Obama. But does that really matter in scope of the question I asked? In normal speech, it's perfectly acceptable about what the picture and painting represent, i.e. "this is Barack Obama". [..]

Comment: @jamesqf [..] And in the exact same vein, while code is merely a representation of an algorithm, it's perfectly fine to refer to what the code represents when looking at the code. Saying "this is bubble sort" when looking at a particular code snippet is no different from saying "this is Barack Obama" when looking at a picture of a painting of Barack Obama; both are perfectly acceptable and commonly understood. The distinction you point out is pedantically correct but simply not observed in conversations because it's an unnecessary roadblock to the flow of conversation.

Comment: The compiled application is "machine code" or "byte code" (depending on the type of compilation), so it's obviously still code.

Comment: I guess an example of code that is not an algorithm would be syntactically incorrect code. I.e. `x := 1 + 2` is a minimal algorithm, but `x := 1 +` is no algorithm, because there is no instruction that can be reasonably inferred. However, it is still code - what else would it be? It's surely not natural language.

Comment: @Flater re: Obama you might be alluding to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images

Comment: Along the lines of the recipe example (but also "closer" to coding) I'll note that both of my kids in elementary school have recently been taught the word "algorithm" when learning various operations in math. Its a perfect usage of the word, IMO, but also may have the effect of a generational change in how many people are familiar with it in contexts outside of ComSci.

Comment: @Flater: Whose ordinary conversations are we referring to?  The OP does refer to an ordinary conversation where the distinction is (wrongly) made.  Otherwise, the great majority of conversations where the term comes up are in CS classes &c, where the distinction is important.  Don't know about you, but I really don't talk about algorithms outside of that context :-)

Comment: _"But I doubt you were specifically talking about a compiled file, given that Python is an interpreted language"_ - Languages aren't "interpreted" or "compiled", implementations are. And the default Python implementation, CPython, actually compiles Python code to bytecode (which can be stored in `.pyc` files), which is run in a VM. Of course, it's very likely they were talking about the source, but even for Python, that's not guaranteed ;)

Comment: @Flater Technically you are right, but maybe the engineer didn't want to be pedantic. When compared to the code someone might use the term algorithm to indicate the pseudo-code, that would be a way to abstract the sequence of instructions from the technical details of the language.

Comment: ‘declarations are essential to the well-defined nature of the instructions’ – but that still doesn’t make them algorithms; being a necessary prerequisite for X doesn’t make something X. ‘compiled application is still an algorithm but has ceased to be code’ – have you ever heard the phrase ‘machine code’?

Comment: The civil engineer said "he didn't know what "code" was" and, as you said, "All code is essentially an algorithm". Additionally the CE said ""code" was something else". To me, just looks like the civil engineer didn't know "code" has an additional meaning, and just used familiar terminology. As such your answer seems needlessly antagonistic and honestly somewhat petty.

Comment: I have to disagree with "All code is essentially an algorithm." For one thing the definition "algorithm is an effective method" denies the possibility of bugs in the code.  What about class definitions for simple objects that lack any logic.  Say you are calling an api to get the 'quote of the day' and define a typescript interface `interface Response { quote: string }`.  This is code by itself as it is written in valid typescript syntax and gives information to the compiler, but it has no steps and cannot be considered an algorithm.

Comment: @JannPoppinga: If invalid code is still code, why would an invalid algorithm not be an algorithm? It's one or the other. When syntactically invalid (or illegible), it either ceases to be both or neither.

Comment: @FluidCode: So in not wanting to be pedantic, the engineer decided to halt the conversation and argue about which specific words should and shouldn't be used?

Comment: This is not quite right. The code is not the algorithm. The code is one way to express the algorithm. They are *never* the same thing. The algorithm is like the plot of the novel, and the code is like the text of the novel.

Comment: The speculation about the civil engineer's motives is not warranted (as is any speculation about other people's motives - in most cases it is completely wrong). Maybe he was rattling off what he was taught by some very intense teacher? Who knows?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat: That has been explicitly addressed in the answer. Class definitions to the _well-defined_ nature of the logic itself. So [Foo class + logic that uses Foo class] is an algorithm, whereas [logic that uses Foo class] is not well-defined (since it has no definition of Foo, yet uses it). In other words, the class might not contains operations itself, but its existence is an essential part of the operations that _do_ solve the problem at hand. Note that I said "All code is essentially an algorithm", not "Any arbitrary snippet of partial code is inherently an algorithm by itself".

Comment: I have a recollection from school to the effect that algorithms must have a termination, and not all coded programs terminate, for instance an operating system.

Comment: Found that the requirement of termination is still being taught, at least in some schools. http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~pouchet/lectures/doc/888.11.algo.6.pdf

Comment: @user368564: I would say that interrupting the flow of conversation to change a word you already understood (because otherwise how could he correct it if he didn't understand it) is needlessly antagonistic and petty.

Comment: @Flater Oh for sure, the civil engineer was needlessly antagonistic and petty. But two wrongs don't make a right, no need to lower yourself to the civil engineer's level.

Answer (score 82):

*Algorithm* and *code* are different, but related things. The relationship is simple: *Code* expresses *algorithms*.

The same algorithm could be expressed in different languages, including natural language, some form of pseudocode, machine language and programming languages. Barring natural language and pseudocode, we refer to these representations as code (source code if it is not machine language).

In fact, translating from some languages to others is possible and done routinely from programming languages to machine language, or from a programming language to another. Sometimes from machine language back to a programming language. This evidences that the same algorithm can be expressed in multiple languages, which results in different but equivalent code.

I'm saying that code is more concrete that algorithms. Algorithms are ideas, and we can use code to portray them, study them, compare them, talk about them. *Or have a computer execute them.*

---

> when something goes from being an algorithm to being code?

Algorithms can exist before being portrayed (in code, for example). That is to say, you can figure out how to do something before writing it down. It is the expression that makes it code.

Comment: This. And it doesn't even need to be different languages. An algorithm can be expressed in multiple ways in one and the same language; multiple codes can implement the same idea.

Comment: a canonical example IMO of algorithm vs code/implementation is the software library FFTW (see wikipedia FFTW) which demonstrated that even though a new algorithm may have less multiplication operations on paper --> a code/implementation that has more multiplications can be faster (for example if the implementation/code lives in L1 or L2 cache most of the time).

Comment: re: translation: It used to be common to implement a compiler for a new language by having it compile to C, rather than directly to machine code or even to text assembly language.  Or even for "major" languages, e.g. `f2c` is/was a Fortran compiler that was useful in getting Fortran running on new platforms, before a native optimizing compiler was ported.  (These days, it's more common for languages to target a common optimizing back-end like LLVM or GCC, or to simply interpret because computers are fast enough and have enough RAM for that.)

Comment: Note, however, that depending on the definition of algorithm, not all code expresses and algorithm. (For instance, if algorithm is defined as a program guaranteed to terminate.)

Answer (score 20):

There are already many good answers to your question, so I will not rehash what they have said. They all basically say the same thing: an algorithm is conceptual and code is the manifestation of the concept in a particular programming language. I think the difference here is the *context* of the conversation, which you have not included in your question.

If you are having a general discussion about the bubble sort algorithm without reference to any particular language, then the *subject* of the conversation is the concept of a bubble sort. Therefore "algorithm" is the proper term.

If you are talking about the *implementation* of the bubble sort algorithm in a particular language, then "code" is the correct term.

I rarely use algorithm by itself in a conversation. I typically use both terms in the course of a conversation, depending on whether or not I'm talking about the concept or the implementation.

To say one term is never used and incorrect is just plain silly-talk.

Answer (score 11):

Other answers are good but I'll boil it down for you: 'somebody' is flat out wrong and confused.

Algorithms are conceptual.  In a nutshell: they are a processes for solving problems.  They exist independent of software and computers.  Long-division is an algorithm.  The normal way of finding an entry in a (physical) dictionary is an algorithm.

You are writing algorithms in your code but the same algorithm can be implemented in code in many distinct forms.  In that way, algorithms and code are related but different.

It makes no sense to call your program an algorithm.  You can be fairly certain that 'somebody' knows little to nothing about programming and probably doesn't understand what an algorithm is either.  Now you just have to decide how to handle this 'somebody'.

Answer (score 8):

I will answer from a "craftsperson" perspective (as someone who has *implemented* a lot of **algorithms** through **code**)

*An algorithm is a recipe*. You can write it in plain English. It is a method to achieve a result. It can be more or less efficient.

For instance, if you try to guess a number between 0 and 100 (based on clues such as "too high", or "too low"), you could start from 0 and go up by one step at a time. That would give you the correct result, but require many steps. Or you could start at 50, and always aim for the middle of the valid range (e.g. if the answer is "too high", say 25 next), and you would (generally) get the correct result in less steps.

The efficiency of an algorithm can be determined mathematically. You can review an algorithm (does it give the correct result? is it efficient?) with just pen and paper, or even by discussing it aloud.

Then there's code. Code is always written in a specific programming language. Unless it's completely random and serves no purpose, code will implement various algorithms (usually more than one, for any sizeable program), in order to perform various tasks.

Implement just means: translate the algorithm into computer language. But there is more than one way to perform this translation. For instance, you could use different variable names. You could "package" the code differently (e.g. define various reusable functions, divide the functions into modules, etc.). There is a lot of craftsmanship involved at that level, in order to keep the code readable and maintainable.

If I review someone's code, I will check that the algorithms are correct (and correctly translated into code: should that index start at 1, or start at 0? should this be a "<" or a "<=", etc.), but I will also check that **coding standards** were followed (not just that the code compiles, but that it conforms to the way code is meant to be written within my organisation)

So as you can see, code and algorithm are related, but also very different things.
And it's *probable* that what you were discussing was code, not algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

**A quick but loose argument**

A shorter argument is clearer and simpler, and might help you convince your "somebody":

- "Much code" - works
- "Much text" - works
- "Much algorithm" - doesn't work
- "Much algorithms" - doesn't work
- "Many algorithms" - does work
- "Many functions" - does work
- "Many code" - doesn't work

**In your situation:**

> When I was talking, I said "code", to refer to a Python program

That is correct. The **code** refers to *all* of the source code.

> He told me that he didn't know what "code" was, that the correct term
> was "algorithm". That "code" was something else.

I don't agree with your "somebody". An algorithm can refer to a particular function, or a few very tightly coupled functions, but not all of the code in a Python file.

So on a python-file(s) dimension, code is all of the text in the file(s), and algorithm is the instructions within each function.

**Beyond files**

However, there is a more natural dimension to consider outside of files. Consider the "Binary Search" algorithm. This is an *idea* before any code text is typed into a text editor. Consider how mathematical notation can describe an algorithm, or animations, or diagrams. The algorithm is an idea. An algorithm can be implemented in different ways in the same language (as code). Fourier Transform is an algorithm, Fast Fourier Transform is a more efficient algorithm, and then there are optimisations for that algorithm and various ways to implement in code.

(Going back to files, when the FFT or Binary Search function is referred to, it might be communicated as "check the Binary Search algorithm". Although that refers to the function code, the speaker is still using the high-level idea's name to nominate the function scope of code)

---

**The nature of code**

For deeper insight into the difference, consider: A programming language is just data that the compiler reads to compile the object code (binary).

In an object-oriented language like C#, the term `class` is more like HTML markup, it tells the compiler about how to organise the *algorithms* that are defined within *functions* (or property getter and setters). It becomes more obvious when you explore the compiled CIL (.Net byte code) which is more of a database of functions (algorithms). The `Attribute` tags are not algorithms that is procedurally run, they are decorations that might lead to some code (algorithms) being run.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between algorithm and code is like the difference between plot and story.

Algorithms refer to how something works. Code is how it is implemented.

The "hero's journey" is a plot. You can write several stories based on this plot. One example is Star Wars (A New Hope).

When referring to a Python program it is code. How the code works is the algorithm.

So basically you are right.

To explain it to the Civil Engineer you can tell him that the statics and dynamics equations he uses to design bridges is the "algorithm". On the other hand the drawing he produces when designing the bridges is the "code". The algorithm is the "theory" and code is the result of trying to implement the theory.

Comment: I was thinking story vs book, but yours works better

Answer (score 4):

The question you actually ask is this:

> When does something go from being an algorithm to being code, if it can change. Maybe it can be both at the same time?

But I think the background you present is rather more relevant.

---

'Code' also has other meanings than 'program code'. See e.g. the [definitions in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/code).

The sense that's probably closest to computing is the meaning of *"a system of signals or symbols for communication"*, as in Morse code, or [8b/10b code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8b/10b_encoding). Base64 is also a code, though usually called 'encoding', probably to separate from the sense of 'program code'.

Also, 'code' can also mean mean laws, rules and regulations, e.g. quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_code): *"For the traffic code in the United States, each state has its own traffic code..."*. Also, building codes, etc. I've never seen the word used in this sense in a programming or computing context, again probably because it would be confusing, but a civil engineer may well meet a number of laws and regulations called 'codes' in their work.

Now, I wouldn't use the word 'algorithm' for program code. Even though program code obviously is *"a step-by-step procedure for solving a problem or accomplishing some end"* [(M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/algorithm), I would reserve the word for the more abstract concept. A program can implement an algorithm, though.

In any case, I would at least apply Hanlon's razor here, and refrain from interpreting them as purposefully facetious, and instead assume the mismatch is about differing customs or such. You also mention their background with Pascal and BASIC, and also reflect on how you see the word used nowadays on the Internet. Those don't strike me as the latest popular thing. Anecdotally, I've mostly seen Matlab in engineering studies in recent years. This could hint at a generational gap, which might also influence the accepted jargon.

Now, they probably shouldn't flat out claim to your face that you are wrong. That rather shows they're ignorant of the different usages of the word in different contexts, but that doesn't mean you need to be.

Answer (score 0):

The question is marked as answered, but I'll add my opinion because I think that the accepted answer is too harsh.

An algorithm is a logical sequence of instructions, the code is one possible implementation. So the code itself could be seen as a way to show the algorithm, but it cannot be considered the only possible representation of that algorithm. The technical details of the language often influence the way the algorithm is expressed.

I don't know what was the engineer thinking, but I know that in the mathemetical environment the formal pseudo-code was developed in order to abstract the algorithms from the technical details of the programming languages, so, it may be possible that this is what the engineer was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithms do not have comments. Code is more all-encompassing and can refer to a whole program or a single comment or part of an expression.

Whether you were talking about an algorithm or not, I can’t say.  But you’d never say something like the algorithm is on the file share x or in the directory x on my computer or I haven’t checked in the algorithm yet (although you might say you haven’t got the algorithm working yet).

Algorithm is very specific and not the correct term for most programs/applications.  A web browser is not an algorithm, neither is word processor.  A sort utility could come close to being called an algorithm, so it might not be totally inappropriate.

An algorithm will almost always refer to a subset of the code in an application. Depending upon language this subset may be referred to as function, procedure, routine, method or some other term that refers to an specific part of the application  The code can incorrectly implement the algorithm so even in this case, they aren’t totally interchangeable.  But they are loosely interchangeable at that level, you might highlight a portion of the code and say to someone “in this part of the algorithm a lower bound is checked”, the word code could work just as well.

But frankly, it sounds like your civil engineer was jerking you around, trying to bullshit instead of addressing any real concern.